# How do I list all core templates?

Tags: 8, theming

Is there a way to list or get all the Drupal 8 core templates which are being used by a site? The list should exclude the templates coming from the theme.

The method I am using is enabling Twig debugging in the services.yml and checking whether a template is from core using a browser's inspector, but this is tedious.

Comment: Why would you like to get a list of all used core templates

Comment: So that I can override them / replace them with my own templates.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a way to get a list of all core templates, but if you want to override them here is a perfect guide, [Drupal core template naming](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/twig-template-naming-conventions)